# Sending files through Laravel HTTP is resulting in unrecognised files on the other end

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

I am having a strange issue when trying to attach images to a HTTP request in Laravel. I am using the following code to send a file to a 3rd party api, but the 3rd party is only receiving partial files ... Am i missing some settings ... There are no errors being reported and I am getting a 'successful' response;

```php
$request = Http::withHeaders(
  [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ]
)
->attach(
  'firstupload',
  Storage::get('/uploads/firstupload.jpeg'),
  'firstupload.' . Storage::mimeType('/uploads/firstupload.jpeg'),
)
->attach(
  'secondupload',
  Storage::get('/uploads/secondupload.jpeg'),
  'secondupload.' . Storage::mimeType('/uploads/secondupload.jpeg'),
)
->post(
  'https://thirdpartyapi.com/fileUpload',
  [
    'uploadType' => 'imageUpload',
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the header to multipart/form-data

```
$request = Http::withHeaders(
 [
  'Accept' => 'multipart/form-data', 
 ]
)
```

**UPDATE:**

I think your code is just fine but you need to do the following

replace **Storage::get('/uploads/firstupload.jpeg'),** with **file_get_contents("storage/path/uploads/firstupload.jpeg"),**

event though your Accept is also okay it can be **application/json**

Comment: Are you sure about that? ... When i inspect the $request ... It automatically adds it because of the ->attach  properties

Comment: Yes it does `return $this->bodyFormat('multipart');` .. So it automatically adds it

Comment: @CodeSauce The request which consists of files must always have a header of 
** "Accept" => "multipart/form-data" ** because file can't be sent via ** 'Accept' => 'application/json', ** if you want to send via a json format then you have to convert your image into a base64 otherwise use the multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

The issue maybe in `Storage::mimeType`. It returns `image/jpeg`. Your file name will become `firstupload.image/jpeg` and `secondupload.image/jpeg`. And the thirdparty read the last segment of your file names. i.e. `jpeg`. Maybe mistaking them for the same file. Try to use `pathinfo(storage_path($path), PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` instead.

```
$request = Http::withHeaders(
  [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ]
)
->attach(
  'firstupload',
  Storage::get('/uploads/firstupload.jpeg'),
  'firstupload.' . pathinfo(storage_path('/uploads/firstupload.jpeg'), PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
)
->attach(
  'secondupload',
  Storage::get('/uploads/secondupload.jpeg'),
  'secondupload.' . pathinfo(storage_path('/uploads/secondupload.jpeg'), PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
)
->post(
  'https://thirdpartyapi.com/fileUpload',
  [
    'uploadType' => 'imageUpload',
  ]
);
```

Comment: Does it matter that the main Storage drive is S3? ... Will with pathinfo(storage_path still retrieve from S3?